# dateTimePicker only returning today's date in vb express

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker, sql-date-functions

I have a vb net project where I have multiple forms each outfitted with a datetimepicker.

For some reason, my datetimepicker in any form isn't returning the selected value i pick but rather, it only returns the current date. I'm ultimately trying to get a string out of the datetimepicker in the format of "YYYYMMDD" (i.e Jan 12, 2016 = "20160112") using a private function below:

for example I picked on my datetimepicker Jan 12, 2016. However the function computes y = 2016, m = 6, and d = 9 as today is Jul 9, 2016.

```
Private Function getdatefromdatepicker() As String
    Dim y, m, d As String
    y = Me.DateTimePicker.Value.Year.ToString()
    m = Me.DateTimePicker.Value.Month.ToString()
    d = Me.DateTimePicker.Value.Day.ToString()
    Return y & m & d
End Function
```

I'm lost with this. If someone could solve how to extract the selected date and get the string format I desire, that would be great. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Strange... I just copied your code to a test and works perfectly. By the way you could do `Return DateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd")`

Comment: Firstly, get rid of that code altogether.  All you need is `Me.DateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd")`.  Secondly, there's no reason that your code wouldn't work that I can see so I can only assume that it's being called in the wrong place or at the wrong time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DateTimePicker` exposes the DateTime value through the `Value` property.  You can then use use Day, Month and Year to get the values like so:

```
 int day = DateTimePicker.Value.Day;
 int month = DateTimePicker.Value.Month;
 int year = DateTimePicker.Value.Year;
```